# Check request URL for pattern

Tags: urls

I need help. I’m making a plugin in woo which add html when URL contains a specific word.

I used `get_site_url`, `get_permalink`, and others but strangely none was sending the information. Finally I decided use `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and works but on some pages doesn’t. Why is this happening? What can I do?

Comment: you should be using the API and not superglobals, but it would help to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

how's the URL structure? Could you paste here?

If you're URL follows this structure: `http://example.com/?foo=bar`, so you need to get the `foo` value with this:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['foo'] ) ) {
   $bar_value = $_GET['foo'];
   // Do whatever you want with $bar_value.
} else {
  // Do something else.
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could test `get_query_var()`function, here is the [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/). This should work like the code below in a simple way.

Tell me if any of this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` isn't working sometimes, but here's one way to check if the requested URL contains a phrase using the core `WP` class:

```
<?php

    global $wp;

    $magic_phrase = 'abracadabra';
    $request_path = $wp->request;

    if (preg_match('/.*'. $magic_phrase .'.*/', $request_path)) {
        // Phrase matches, do what you need here!
    }

?>
```

That'll match any URL that contains "abracadabra" at any position in the URL. You can/should update the regex used to check the request path against your phrase to make sure you're not matching paths you don't intend to.

The core `WP` class does a bit of extra magic with the request to make sure it's consistent and using it instead of server variables might help a bit.